# Can MSAL be used with swift UI based app?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, azure-ad-msal

I have an app that used SwiftUI instead of UIKit. I want to use MSAL library to acquire a token interactively. I see that MSALWebviewParameters support display using UIViewController. Is there a way to use swift ui based views here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

In your `SceneDelegate` you will have something like

```
 window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
```

That `UIHostingController` instance is what you need to pass to MSAL

Comment: What would be the proper way to access that window.rootViewController? For example, I have a separate view and view model, and the view model is where this MSALWebviewParameters exists.

Comment: You could add it to your model or add it to the environment

Comment: thank you for your response. I think I have a workable solution.

Comment: Is there any sample which shows how to use MSAL with SwiftUI? Github has only a Storyboard sample.

Comment: I don't know of any examples. Pp What exactly are you struggling with. The authentication should be handled by your model, not your SwiftUI views. As long as the model has the view controller reference it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: You mean a model should be created and referenced in the content view?

Comment: Yes. Typically you would have a data model and you will trigger some data fetch in that model. The data fetch needs a token. If it doesn't have a token or the token is expired then you perform an authentication.  You can create your model in your scene delegate where you have a reference to the hosting view controller and pass that to your model. Put the model in your environment.  I haven't yet looked at how it would work in a "pure SwiftUI" app in iOS14.

Comment: I tried to figure out how to do it but it can't be done with pure SwiftUI yet as I understand. How-t-do-it posts in the internet seems to use both UIKit and SwiftUI. I hope Xcode 12 final release may make pure SwiftUI work with FactBook,MSAL, google login, etc.

Comment: @Aussie did you find a video tutorial on this?

Comment: I'm a SwiftUI newbie here. Where is the SceneDelegate? I'm creating a pure SwiftUI app, but I don't see a SceneDelegate anywhere.

Comment: You don't have a scene delegate if you use pure SwiftUI